# AJAX function not recognising json return

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am calling an online API via an HTML form which sends back class timetables. I am populating the timetable on the initial page load then then using jQuery and AJAX to get filtered classes.

The problem I am having is that my AJAX function is not recognising the data that is being sent as JSON. I am ensuring the data is sent back using 'json_encode' in the PHP function and that the 'dataType' is 'json' in the jQuery.
No code is running in the 'success' callback in the AJAX function because of this. Here is my code:

AJAX:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(document).on("change", "#calendar-filter-form select", function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type      :   'POST',   
            dataType  :   'json',
            data      :   jQuery("#calendar-filter-form").serialize(),
            url       :   "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>",
            success   : function(data) {
                if(data) {  
                    alert("test");
                    var html = "";
                    jQuery(data.results).each(function(i, v) {
                        alert(v);
                        html += '<div class="day">';
                        html += '<h3>' + v.day + '</h3>';
                        jQuery(v).each(function(i2, v2) {
                            html += '<div class="activity-item">';
                                html += '<h4>' + v2.SessionName + '</h4>;'
                                html += '<p class="session-time">Time: ' + v.Time + 'Start</p>';
                                html += '<p class="remaining-capacity">Remaining Spaces: ' + v.RemainingCapacity + '</p>';
                            html += '</div>';
                        });
                        html += '</div>';
                    });
                    jQuery("#calendar").html(html);
                }
            }           
        });
    });
});
```

And the PHP that is calling the API and returning the data:

```
if(isset($_POST['filterClasses'])) {
    $url = '/classes/search?FacilityId=1';
    $options = array();
    foreach($_POST as $key => $postItem) {
        if(!empty($postItem)) {             
            $url .= "&ActivityName=" . urlencode($postItem);                
            $options['url'] = $url;             
        }
    }
    $results = makecURLRequest($options);
    $resultsSorted = array();
    $resultsDecoded = json_decode($results);
    $filters = array();
    $resultsSorted = array();
    $days = array('Monday' => 1, 'Tuesday' => 2, 'Wednesday' => 3, 'Thursday' => 4, 'Friday' => 5, 'Saturday' => 6, 'Friday' => 7);
    foreach($days as $key => $day) {
        $resultsSorted[$day] = array();
        $resultsSorted[$day]['day'] = $key;     
        foreach($resultsDecoded as $result) {       
            if($result->DayOfWeek == $day) {
                $timestamp = strtotime($result->Time);
                array_push($resultsSorted[$day], $result);
            }                           
        }
    }   
    header('Content-Type: application/json', true);
    echo json_encode(array("results" => $resultsSorted));
}
```

Here is the return JSON from the API:

```
 [
    {
        "ActivityInstanceId":11959,
        "FacilityId":1,
        "SessionName":"Swim Scheme Lessons",
        "GroupId":null,
        "DayOfWeek":4,
        "Time":"2014-01-23T16:00:00",
        "RemainingCapacity":1,
        "Description":null,
    },
    {
        "ActivityInstanceId":11959,
        "FacilityId":1,
        "SessionName":"Swim Scheme Lessons",
        "GroupId":null,
        "DayOfWeek":4,
        "Time":"2014-01-23T16:00:00",
        "RemainingCapacity":1,
        "Description":null,
    },
...
```

I cannot seem to see why this is not being recognised as valid JSON. Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show the actual output on the PHP page? Objects somewhere in your result (`json_encode`) can sometimes break the structure of the JSON string.

Comment: Sure. The output at the point of return in the PHP or the output back to the AJAX function?

Comment: The PHP one. So we can read the raw JSON string.

Comment: Are the any errors in the console, did you try adding a error handler to the ajax call to see what is says etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out what it was that was happening. I was submitting the AJAX request to the same page (to php above the html tags) and it was trying to reload the whole page again, including php variables that had been sent on the initial page load. This was causing the AJAX function to not work correctly.
I usually work within MVC frameworks and wasn't this time so it threw me off a little.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

your json is not valid.

```
{
        "ActivityInstanceId":11959,
        "FacilityId":1,
        "SessionName":"Swim Scheme Lessons",
        "GroupId":null,
        "DayOfWeek":4,
        "Time":"2014-01-23T16:00:00",
        "RemainingCapacity":1,
        "Description":null ***,***
    },
```

suppose to be:

```
{
            "ActivityInstanceId":11959,
            "FacilityId":1,
            "SessionName":"Swim Scheme Lessons",
            "GroupId":null,
            "DayOfWeek":4,
            "Time":"2014-01-23T16:00:00",
            "RemainingCapacity":1,
            "Description":null
        },
```

and the lest element there is no need for ",".

and try to add

```
if(data) { data = JSON.parse(data ) }
```

In your js.
its suppose to work.